# Removing "\r" while expanding file in shell

Tags: shell, glob, carriage-return, mv

I was trying to move a file name containing a particular string to another directory in a shell script, but during the filename expansion I am getting \r in the file

```
Local_Input_Landing_Dir=`grep Local_Input_Landing_Dir $CFILE | awk -F= ' {print $2} '`

src_dir="$Local_Input_Landing_Dir"/*_vendor.csv

echo 'before' $src_dir
```

The o/p of the above echo is being spliing over to next line

```
before /stage/Scripts/ecommerce/vendor/Data_split_vendor
/*vendor.csv
```

When I try using the move command, I get \r while expansion

```
mv $src_dir $Local_Input_Landing_Dir/current_date_dir/
   mv: cannot stat `/stage/Scripts/ecommerce/vendor/Data_split_vendor\r/*_vendor.csv': No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are developing on Windows and use your script on a Unix machine you should convert your files (the new line character is `\r\n`on windows and `\n` on unix)

Use the command

```
  dos2unix your_file
```

Comment: @CharydeBE so this is caused by the \r coming from the i/p file ?